# PowerBuilder 2019 R3 - Is it the filter method which caused the application to crash?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, powerbuilder, datawindow, powerbuilder-pfc

Our windows application was developed in PowerBuilder 8 and it has been migrated to PowerBuilder 2019 R3. The PB 8 build application is not crashing for a very long time and the filter method is working properly. When it was migrated to PB2019 R3 and deployed to production, the application crashes when it reached the line of code with the filter method. When the PB IDE is in the debugging mode, it did not encounter the crashing so I've implemented a message box every 20 to 30 lines and re-build the EXE, to narrow down where exactly the cause of crashing inside the function and that's how I figured out, the crashing occurs when the execution is in the line of filter method.

Is it a PowerBuilder bug specifically in the filter method? Appreciate any idea or thoughts on how to resolve the mentioned crashing issue.

Here is the code of the function of_filter( )  with an argument type of string :as_status

```
String  ls_filter
integer li_rc
Long        ll_primary_rowcount, ll_filter_rowcount
Long    ll_row
long    ll_rows
long    ll_found
decimal ld_job_id
string  ls_sort
string  ls_server_date_time
long        ll_job_search

DateTime ldt_ship_date, ldt_cancel_date

dw_list.SetRedraw( FALSE )
iuo_parent.SetRedraw( FALSE)
ib_filter_in_progress = true

IF iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Rowcount() > 0 THEN
    ld_job_id = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.object.job_id[iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Getrow()]
End If

ll_primary_rowcount = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.RowCount()
ll_filter_rowcount = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.FilteredCount()


IF ll_filter_rowcount > 0 THEN
    li_rc = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.RowsMove &
    (1, ll_filter_rowcount, Filter!, &
    iuo_parent.dw_job_search, 1, Primary!)
END IF

iuo_parent.dw_job_search.SetFilter(" ")
MessageBox("Debugging","of_Filter : Begin Filter")
iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Filter( ) //This is the line where the application crashes.
MessageBox("Debugging","of_Filter : End Filter")

ll_rows = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.RowCount()
    
CHOOSE CASE as_status
    CASE 'W'
    ls_server_date_time = string(sqlca.of_get_server_datetime(),"YYYY-MM-DD")
    
    ls_sort = 'Long(bill_customer_no) A, enter_date A, prefix_sort A'
    ls_filter = "( isnull(ship_date) and status not in ( 'CANCEL' , 'STKCANCL') ) "+&
                "or (date(ship_date) = "+ls_server_date_time+") "+&
                    "or (status in ( 'CANCEL', 'STKCANCL' ) "+&
                         " and date(cancel_date) = "+ls_server_date_time+")"
    
    dw_list.Object.date_holder_t.text = 'Ship Date'
    
    FOR ll_row = 1 TO ll_rows
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = dw_list.Object.ship_date[ll_row]
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Object.ship_date[ll_row]
        
        ldt_ship_date = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.GetItemDateTime(ll_Row,'ship_date')
        IF NOT ISNULL(ldt_ship_date) THEN 
            dw_List.SetItem(ll_Row,'date_holder',ldt_ship_date)
        END IF
        
    NEXT

    CASE 'S'
    ls_sort = 'Long(bill_customer_no) A, ship_date A, prefix_sort A'
    dw_list.Object.date_holder_t.text = 'Ship Date'

    FOR ll_row = 1 TO ll_rows
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = dw_list.Object.ship_date[ll_row]
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Object.ship_date[ll_row]
        
        ldt_ship_date = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.GetItemDateTime(ll_Row,'ship_date')
        IF NOT ISNULL(ldt_ship_date) THEN 
            dw_List.SetItem(ll_Row,'date_holder',ldt_ship_date)
        END IF
    NEXT

    ls_filter = 'Not IsNull( ship_date )'

    CASE 'C'
    ls_sort = 'Long(bill_customer_no) A, cancel_date A, prefix_sort A'
    dw_list.Object.date_holder_t.text = 'Cancel Date'
    
    FOR ll_row = 1 TO ll_rows
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Object.cancel_date[ll_row]
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = dw_list.Object.cancel_date[ll_row]
        
        ldt_cancel_date = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.GetItemDateTime(ll_Row,'cancel_date')
        IF NOT ISNULL(ldt_cancel_date) THEN 
            dw_List.SetItem(ll_Row,'date_holder',ldt_cancel_date)
        END IF
    NEXT
    ls_filter = 'Not IsNull( cancel_date )'

    CASE 'A'
    ls_sort = 'Long(bill_customer_no) A, enter_date A, prefix_sort A'
    ls_filter = ''
    dw_list.Object.date_holder_t.text = 'Ship Date'
    
    FOR ll_row = 1 TO ll_rows
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Object.ship_date[ll_row]
        //dw_list.Object.date_holder[ll_row] = dw_list.Object.ship_date[ll_row]
        
        ldt_ship_date = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.GetItemDateTime(ll_Row,'ship_date')
        IF NOT ISNULL(ldt_ship_date) THEN 
            dw_List.SetItem(ll_Row,'date_holder',ldt_ship_date)
        END IF
    NEXT        

END CHOOSE

li_rc = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.SetFilter( ls_filter )
If IsNull(li_rc) or li_rc < 1 Then
     error.of_application_error(this,"of_filter",&
         "Error encountered when setting filter.~r~n"+&
          "   Return code = "+f_null_check(li_rc)+"~r~n"+&
          "   Filter command = "+f_null_check(ls_filter))
End IF
    
li_rc = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Filter()
If IsNull(li_rc) or li_rc < 1 Then
     error.of_application_error(this,"of_filter",&
         "Error encountered when filtering job list.~r~n"+&
          "   Return code = "+f_null_check(li_rc)+"~r~n"+&
          "   Filter command = "+f_null_check(ls_filter))
End IF

li_rc = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.SetSort( ls_sort )
If IsNull(li_rc) or li_rc < 1 Then
     error.of_application_error(this,"of_filter",&
         "Error encountered when setting sort criteria.~r~n"+&
          "   Return code = "+f_null_check(li_rc)+"~r~n"+&
          "   Sort command = "+f_null_check(ls_sort))
End IF

li_rc = iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Sort()
If IsNull(li_rc) or li_rc < 1 Then
     error.of_application_error(this,"of_filter",&
         "Error encountered when sorting job list.~r~n"+&
          "   Return code = "+f_null_check(li_rc)+"~r~n"+&
          "   Sort command = "+f_null_check(ls_sort))
End IF

ib_filter_in_progress = false

//  Put the current row back to the same job id if the job id exists
//  in the current list.

ll_found = 0
IF not ISNULL(ld_job_id) and ld_job_id <> 0 THEN 
    ll_found=iuo_parent.dw_job_search.Find("job_id = " +    `String(ld_job_id),1,iuo_parent.dw_job_search.RowCount())`
End If
If ll_found = 0 or ll_found <> iuo_parent.dw_job_search.getrow() or ll_found > 0 Then
        iuo_parent.dw_job_search.ScrollTorow(max(1,ll_found))
End If


dw_list.SetRedraw( TRUE )
iuo_parent.SetRedraw( TRUE)

THIS.Event vs_set_environment()
```

In addition, I was able to reproduced the issue on both Oracle 10g and 19c environments and here is the event Log description of the crash:

Faulting application name: customer.exe, version: 5.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x6100e416
Faulting module name: orageneric12.dll, version: 12.2.0.1, time stamp: 0x58a2624c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x01136007
Faulting process ID: 0x4578
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9c4e68bb84a68
Faulting application path: C:\SourceTree\Build Release\V05.22.00-VSDEV819\customer\customer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Oracle\Win.32\12.2_InstantClient\bin\orageneric12.dll
Report ID: a16e707a-0f52-40d3-8fb2-e868019a4cd3
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

[image]

Comment: What value does SetFilter return?

Comment: Why are you setting the filter to a space?  Why not SetFilter('') ?

Comment: Is that last IF block needed?  It looks like the intent of that was to reset the filter (moving filtered rows to primary buffer) but it wouldn't be needed because setting the filter to empty string would do the same thing.  I would try commenting that block out, and change the SetFilter to be an empty string rather than a space.